# Is there any benefit of using async in non async database drivers?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, database-connection, fastapi, connection-pooling

I'm learning fastAPI - and encountered concept of concurrency. From point of view of database transactions assume that underlying driver is not 'async enabled', so to speak. For my API,for each call to it, it does a simple GET request to underlying database.If the bottleneck is actually the transaction times themselves, does this mean that:

1. There is not much benefit in using async/await - as underlying driver doesn't support concurrency
2. using a connection pool would be an alternative(I'm aware it's a different thing altogether)

- went to docs - learnt about await - but mostly they use psychopg(async)
- I expect connection pooling will provide a small advantage

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804)

Comment: @Chris thanks a lot. that is one amazing answer, and as the comments explain - a real pity that's not included in main documentation

Comment: yes it did.So from I gathered - apart from what you mentioned - if you use async (but don't use await ) - that actually would lead to sync behaviour as the eventloop would run on the main thread. From what it appears - it's better to NOT include async in my case(fastAPI will still treat create async behaviour as it uses external threads for that endpoint that is awaited)